# Let $T$ be a linear operator in a vector space $V$ such as $T$ admits an ajoint. Prove that if $T^*T=0$ then $T=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, inner-products, adjoint-operators

**Let $T$ be a linear operator in a vector space $V$ such as $T$ admits an ajoint. Prove that if $T^*T=0$ then $T=0$.**

I tried to do the following:

If $v\in V$ then $0=\left< v,T^*T(v)\right>=\left< T(v),T(v)\right>$ then $||T(v)||=0$ and so $T(v)=0$ for every $v\in V$.

Is this correct?

Comment: It is, assuming your assumption was that $T^*T = 0$.

Comment: It is correct, but there is no need to mention $\|Tv\|=0$. By the definition of inner product, the only vector $y$ that satisfies $\langle y,y\rangle=0$ is zero.

Comment: Your answer is correct.